# Not a git repository after clone

Tags: git

I have cloned a git repository

I can see the branch using

```
git branch -a
```

but when I used `git status` command, it is telling me it's not a git repository

So how to make it git repository?

These are the command which I have applied

```
git clone branchname foldername
cd foldername
git checkout branchname
git branch -a
```

then its displaying all the branch list

```
git status
```

then its displaying  not a git repository

the log details for Git is

```
commit f06d2102a19ee70c86c2f398f2d670b1b2ed51e2
Author: Abhijith Srivatsav <abhijith.srivatsav@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Dec 12 16:02:36 2012 +0530

    updating libraries

commit 80b8258e1823f5b652808f680dab75859b200736
Author: Abhijith Srivatsav <abhijith.srivatsav@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Dec 12 15:54:19 2012 +0530

    updating actionbarsherlock

commit 18919ea02c245e9b270aa2b70b68045d777ec16d
Author: Abhijith Srivatsav <abhijith.srivatsav@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Dec 12 15:41:18 2012 +0530

    New Card Manager with project structure changes

commit 7d838b0e470c7634f7b5845b89ddb32420f198b7
Author: Abhijith Srivatsav <abhijith.srivatsav@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Dec 12 15:15:14 2012 +0530

    New Card Manager and project structure cleanup
```

Comment: What happens when you try "`git checkout master`"?

Comment: Can you paste all the commands you typed here?

Comment: yeah sure these are the commands which I have applied

Comment: Its telling not a git repository Tadeck

Comment: I have edited and pasted all the commands please have a look

Comment: You need to type "cd foldername" before git branch -a

Comment: yeah that I did . I am in that folder only

Comment: `git clone branchname`? Presumably you don't actually mean that because you don't clone branches in git, you clone repositories.

Comment: Please see the log file . cloning already worked

Comment: @user1825863: if the repo doesn't contain sensitive data, could you also post the output of `ls -lA` ?

Comment: I am sorry Nevik ..iT contains sensitive data

Answer (score 1):

Your `git clone branchname foldername` doesn’t make any sense at all – you can’t clone branches. This command probably caused a rather wierd situation. Could you show us the output of these command, please:

```
cd ../..
find -name .git
```